Storage issues ubuntu 24.04
I am using sudo apt-get clean, autoclean, and autoremove. My cache is full and only clears one percent. What is the correct way to free  up some space from the command line?
Here is the result of running df -h:
/dev/root        6.8G  6.6G  105M  99% /
tmpfs            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            764M  964K  763M   1% /run
tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
efivarfs         128K  3.6K  120K   3% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p16  881M   76M  744M  10% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p15  105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs            382M   12K  382M   1% /run/user/1000


The commands stated are the correct ones to remove unused packages and clean the package cache.
Please edit your question and add information how you determine "only clears one percent".
Please also add information if "free up some space" is related to the package cache only or do you have general issues with disc space.

df -h will show the space on your mounted storage drives; fwiw.

Thanks, when i log in I see this statement  Usage of /:   98.3% of 6.71GB. It shifts from 98 to 97%.

Your disk is full. Focus on that. That yout package cache is also full is merely a symptom.

So I took down the whole server and reinstalled everything now  i have  6.8G  4.6G  2.2G  69%. It still seems off I dont know what I can really remove.  It may be that a log is filling up? Do you have any suggestions on what could be being saved thats uncessary on the disk?

The primary reason for running out of space is that your partition you installed Ubuntu Server on is undersized. The resolve the problem, you should increase the size of the partition.
Looking at the system requirements / recommendations for Ubuntu Server, the recommended size is 25GB. However, this of course depends on what other software (webserver, database server, ...) is additionally installed and if any data (webpages, database files, ...) are on the Root-Partition as well.
~2.5 GB disk space is the bare minimum for a minimal installation of Ubuntu Server 24.05, leaving hardly any room to install anything on top of that. A standard installation of Ubuntu Server 24.04 is around 5 GB, leaving hardly any room to install anything else.
Based on the original question you may want to give the partition as size of at least 10GB. Whether this is future-proof or not for the given use case depends on what additional packages and snaps are intended to be installed in the future and which additional data is supposed to be stored on the Root-partition.

Is it possible to add space through aws interface? Rn i went to storage and increased the size to 12 GIb.
